# transition inside <router-view>

Tags: vue.js, transition, vue-router

I trying add transition between change pages and i can't understand hot use  for nested child inside .
If i'll wrap in app.vue  it will animate all blocks:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
      <router-view class="view"></router-view>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>
```

but i need animate only content component, but it now working

for example structure index.vue:

```
<template>
<div>
    <header-component></header-component>
    <div class="content" id="content">
        <transition name="fade">
            <content-component :content="content"></content-component>
        </transition>
        <div class="buffer"></div>
    </div>
    <footer-component></footer-component>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to define transition classes.

```
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to /* .fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

**One example**: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xWjZgM

There's a very detailed official [documentation page](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Staggering-List-Transitions) on Vue transitions.